# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{\delta n^d}}{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left[-\frac{e^{\delta n^d}}{\sqrt{n}}\right]<\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $\delta>0$ and $d>0$. I am pretty sure that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{\delta n^d}}{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left[-\frac{e^{\delta n^d}}{\sqrt{n}}\right]<\infty$$

as it seems that the series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)\exp[-f(n)]$ ought to converge for increasing $f(n)$.

However, I am having trouble formally proving this, though the proof should be well-known if it exists.  Maybe it's obvious and I am overlooking something.  Perhaps I am wrong and my series doesn't converge.  Can someone give a hint or pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is that
$\frac{x^m}{e^x}
\to 0$
as $x \to \infty$
for any positive real $m$.
(This follows from
$e^x > \frac{x^{m+1}}{(m+1)!}$.)

This gives you
$\frac{x}{e^x}
< \frac{c}{x^m}
$
for any positive $c$
for large enough $x$.

Setting
$x = \frac{e^{\delta n^d}}{\sqrt{n}}$,
this gives
$\frac{x}{e^x}
<\frac{c}{x^m}$.

Using the inequality again,
$\frac{\delta n^d}{e^{\delta n^d}}
< \frac{c}{(\delta n^d)^m}
$
and the sum of these converges
if $md > 1$.